# spring 3 scheduling: collection of tasks?

Tags: spring, spring-3

IS it possible to return list of tasks (Runnable?) to spring, so spring execute them in serial order regardless exceptions thrown by each item?

I want spring to call 10 tasks in order: 1, 2, 3 and so on, and simply log exception if it occures

Looks like @Async may help, but how can I configure it from XML?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the tasks serially it can done through a threadpool with just 1 thread in it:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(yourrunnable);
```

You cannot configure `@Async` from xml, it has to be through annotations, also if you are considering @Async, you will need to provide an explicit executor as you want your tasks to be handled serially:

```
@Async("serialExecutor")
<task:executor id="serialExecutor" pool-size="1"/>
```